# Unable to create a button in my Class ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net, button, delegates

So I want to add a asp button after my I create a new instance. I'm having trouble giving the button a name, id, etc. Like so `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />` I'm unable to do this because everytime I try to add parenthesis " " it won't work. Also, I want to be able to give all the Logs a seperate id for each button created. I'm also having trouble removing the output that its creating in the top left hand side corner, why is this appearing twice? I just want it to appear **ONCE** in the middle of the page! Keep in mind, I've search alot of places for this but there are no answers. Any help, I will provide all the code below that is need. Thanks!

---

**Class:**

```
public class WelcomeText
{
    public string Greet;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Visited;

    public WelcomeText(string greet, string name, DateTime visited)
    {
        Greet = greet;
        Name = name;
        Visited = visited;
    }

    public void greetUser(string msg)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(msg + Greet + " " + Name + " " + Visited + "<button></button><br/>");
    }
}
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <section>
        <%=displayWelcomeText()%>
            </section>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public delegate void greetDel(string msg);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // display text
            displayWelcomeText();
        }

        public string displayWelcomeText()
        {
            string greetString = "";
            WelcomeText wT1 = new WelcomeText("Welcome", "Sean", DateTime.Now);
            WelcomeText wT2 = new WelcomeText("Hey", "Test", DateTime.Now);
            WelcomeText wT3 = new WelcomeText("Hello", "User", DateTime.Now);

            greetDel gD1 = new greetDel(wT1.greetUser);
            gD1("Log: ");

            greetDel gD2 = new greetDel(wT2.greetUser);
            gD2("Log: ");

            greetDel gD3 = new greetDel(wT3.greetUser);
            gD3("Log: ");

            return greetString;
        }
    }
```

---

**Problem with my code**
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oy!! More than a few problems to solve here.

First, you see the output twice because you are calling the method named displayWelcomeText() twice: the first time in the Page load and again from the aspx page-code itself, e.g. <%=displayWelcomeText()%>.

If you were to examine the content sent by the server, you'd notice that the first set of text is being sent BEFORE the initial  tag. Then the second set is inside the <div><section> area.

What's wrong with changing the  to be a

Then in the page load method...

```
  myPanel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text=String.Format("{0} {1}, {2:MM/dd/yyyy}", wt.Greet, wt.Name, wt.Visited);
```

That will accomplish what you *say* you want to do. Whether that's going to do anything meaningful is another problem to resolve.

Comment: Thank you very much! So do I remove the method from the page load and add the code you have?